# Custom editable, translatable email templates

Tags: users, emails

I need to send many different emails to drupal users. How can i add custom editable & translatable email templates? Something like user emails?

I have tried "Mail Editor" module, but i don't know how to add custom emails. Perhaps this is not the right solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using Mail Editor you can add custom emails by going to admin/config/system/mail-edit

Did you try doing that?

Regarding translation at - /admin/config/regional/language/configure there is a 'Follow the user's language preference.' option.

Comment: i can't add new mail there. I can only add language translations.